# handling events in java swing

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton, actionlistener

How can I assign two buttons to share the same class for handling events in Java/swing?

For example, I have this:

```
private class BtnEvtHandler implements ActionListener {

        private int counter=10;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gs.setX(counter);
            gs.repaint();
            counter=counter+10;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //action for move button
        }

    }

        JButton jumpBtn= new JButton("JUMP");
        BtnEvtHandler okButtonHandler= new BtnEvtHandler(); 
        (jumpBtn).addActionListener(okButtonHandler);
        menuPanel.add(jumpBtn);
```

Now I want to add another button as below which can have the same class as event handler but dispatches to different actionPerformed as mentioned in above code.

```
        JButton moveBtn= new JButton("MOVE");
        menuPanel.add(moveBtn);
        (moveBtn).addActionListener(okButtonHandler);
```

Comment: Then you can add arguments to your BtnEvtHandler to determine what to do. Something like `public BtnEvtHandler(Object WHAT_TO_DO)` where Object imo should be enum, it may depends on what logic you want to do different inside the event. Then your `actionPerformed` could have a switch statement to determine the logic based on the WHAT_TO_DO argument.

Comment: You can also check the `ActionEvent e` with `e.getSource()`, or `e.getActionCommand()` and decide what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse one `ActionListener` and expect it to call a different method depending on the button you attach it to.  The contract of `ActionListener` has one method that gets called.  But you can check the source of the event and have flow control based on that.  Here's an example:

```
package com.sandbox;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SwingSandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = buildFrame();

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();

        MyActionListener myActionListener = new MyActionListener();

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
        button1.addActionListener(myActionListener);
        pane.add(button1);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button2");
        button2.addActionListener(myActionListener);
        pane.add(button2);


        frame.add(pane);
    }


    private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }


    private static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
            if ("Button1".equals(source.getText())) {
                System.out.println("You clicked button 1");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You clicked button 2");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, I want to have different method event happening for moveBtn which can be a part of BtnEvtHandler class. In other words, I want to have different actionPerformed method for move button.

Comment: Then create a different `ActionListener` for it?  **What have you tried?  What trouble is that causing?**

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades what do you mean by `different`?

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades **What have you tried? What trouble is that causing?**

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades, Don't use the getText() method of the button. The ActionEvent was designed for you to use the getActionCommand() method. It will default to the text of the button, but you can also use the setActionCommand() method of the button to make it different from the text.